# Improve the query by removing the sub query

Tags: sql-server, subquery, query-optimization

I have a Customer table

```
+--------+---------+
| Id     |  Name   |
+--------+---------+
| 1      |   A     |
| 2      |   b     |
| 3      |   c     |
| 4      |   d     |
| 5      |   3     |
| 6      |   f     |
| 7      |   g     |
+--------+---------+
```

and an order table

```
+-----+------+--------------------------+
| ID  | C_Id | OrderDate                |
+-----+------+--------------------------+
| 1   | 1    |  2017-05-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 2   | 2    |  2017-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 3   | 3    |  2017-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 4   | 4    |  2017-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 5   | 1    |  2017-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 6   | 2    |  2017-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 7   | 3    |  2017-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 8   | 4    |  2017-11-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 9   | 2    |  2017-06-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 10  | 3    |  2017-07-12 00:00:00.000 |
+-----+------+--------------------------+
```

I need the result of the customers who did not buy in last month.
That is from the order table Customer 3 and 4 have purchased in last month(November). The result should not include customer 3 and 4 even they had purchase in earlier months.

I have this query which returns the result perfectly.

```
SELECT C_ID , MONTH(OrderDate) from [Order]
WHERE MONTH(OrderDate) <> MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 
AND C_ID NOT IN (
SELECT C_ID FROM [Order] 
WHERE MONTH(OrderDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1)
```

Can anyone help me to write this query without using subquery

**EDIT:**  **For more clarity, I need to exclude the customers from the result(get all orders for current year) if they had any purchase in November, also I need results for this year alone.**

Comment: Why don't you want the subquery? What makes you think that another solution without the subquery would be faster?

Comment: What happens if you leave out the subquery? Looks like that shouldn't include the rows with `MONTH(OrderDate) == MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1` as is.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi I was asked to write the query without subquery. I need to learn the other possible ways to get the expected result

Comment: @daniu if remove the subquery means I will get the customer who has not purchased in November month but still I get customer 3 and 4 in the result which is not my expected result. I need to exclude the customers from the result if they purchased in November.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use another way for checking earlier purchases because with `MONTH(OrderDate) <> MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1` you have a problem if purchases are in different years.
You need to expand your condition. For example

```
(
     (MONTH(OrderDate)<MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) AND YEAR(OrderDate)=YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())))
  OR YEAR(OrderDate)<YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
)
```

Or you can use the `EOMONTH` function (from SQL Server 2012) for it. I think this variant will be more useful.

```
SELECT
  C_ID,
  MONTH(OrderDate)
FROM [Order]
WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)<EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) -- check for month and year
  AND C_ID NOT IN (
          SELECT C_ID FROM [Order] 
          WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) -- check for month and year
        )
```

I think here is more useful using a variable

```
DECLARE @lastMonth date=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))

SELECT
  C_ID,
  MONTH(OrderDate)
FROM [Order]
WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)<@lastMonth -- check for month and year
  AND C_ID NOT IN (
          SELECT C_ID FROM [Order] 
          WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)=@lastMonth -- check for month and year
        )
```

A variant without a subquery

```
SELECT
  C_ID,
  MIN(OrderDate) FirstOrderDate,
  MAX(OrderDate) LastOrderDate
FROM [Order]
WHERE OrderDate<=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
GROUP BY C_ID
HAVING EOMONTH(MAX(OrderDate))<EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
```

Or

```
DECLARE @lastMonth date=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))

SELECT
  C_ID,
  MIN(OrderDate) FirstOrderDate,
  MAX(OrderDate) LastOrderDate
FROM [Order]
WHERE OrderDate<=@lastMonth
GROUP BY C_ID
HAVING EOMONTH(MAX(OrderDate))<@lastMonth
```

But here I return only `MIN(OrderDate)` and `MAX(OrderDate)` but maybe it'll suit you.

I don't think that a variant with a subquery is worse. I think it's more clearly.

```
DECLARE @lastMonth date=EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))

SELECT
  C_ID,
  YEAR(OrderDate) [Year],
  MONTH(OrderDate) [Month]
  COUNT(ID) OrderCount
FROM [Order]
WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)<@lastMonth
  --AND YEAR(OrderDate)=YEAR(@lastMonth) -- if you need only orders from this year
  AND C_ID IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT C_ID
          FROM [Order]
          WHERE EOMONTH(OrderDate)=@lastMonth
        )
GROUP BY C_ID,YEAR(OrderDate),MONTH(OrderDate)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, its wonderful. However I need  the number of orders and its months. The query you posted returns the customer's order first date and last date. Thanks I learnt EOMONTH() from your Answer

Comment: I added one more query at the end of my answer. But it use a subquery. I think without a subquery it'll be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

When working with dated information you cannot just use a month number because month 1 comes after month 12 (of last year). So, work with dates, not month numbers.

For this query we need "this month" and "last month" by their dates (not the month numbers) and we can start with this by using getdate()

A useful "trick" here is to calculate the first day of this month which we can do by calculating the number of months from zero `datediff(month,0, getdate() )`  then adding that number to zero `dateadd(month, ..., 0)`. So once we have the first of this month it is easy to calculate first of last month and first of next month simply by subtracting or adding 1 month.

So, for a solution that will work in any version of SQL Server:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4765b/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    ([ID] int, [C_Id] int, [OrderDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Orders
    ([ID], [C_Id], [OrderDate])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-05-12 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (3, 3, '2017-11-12 00:00:00'),
    (4, 4, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (6, 2, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (7, 3, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (8, 4, '2017-11-12 00:00:00'),
    (9, 2, '2017-06-12 00:00:00'),
    (10, 3, '2017-07-12 00:00:00')
;


CREATE TABLE Customers
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO Customers
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'b'),
    (3, 'c'),
    (4, 'd'),
    (5, '3'),
    (6, 'f'),
    (7, 'g')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @this_month datetime = dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, getdate() ), 0)
declare @last_month datetime = dateadd(month,-1,@this_month)

select
      c.Id
    , c.name
    , count(case when o.OrderDate >= @last_month and o.OrderDate < @this_month then 1 end) last_month
    , count(case when o.OrderDate >= @this_month then 1 end) this_month
from customers c
LEFT join orders o on c.id = o.c_id
                  and OrderDate >= @last_month
                  and OrderDate < dateadd(month,1,@this_month)
group by c.Id, c.name
having count(case when o.OrderDate >= @last_month and o.OrderDate < @this_month then 1 end) = 0
and count(case when o.OrderDate >= @this_month then 1 end) > 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4765b/3/0)**:

```
| Id | name | last_month | this_month |
|----|------|------------|------------|
|  1 |    A |          0 |          1 |
|  2 |    b |          0 |          2 |
```

### ----

```
declare @this_year  datetime = dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, getdate() ), 0)
declare @this_month datetime = dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, getdate() ), 0)
declare @last_month datetime = dateadd(month,-1,@this_month)

select
      c.Id
    , c.name
    , count(case when o.OrderDate >= @last_month and o.OrderDate < @this_month then 1 end) last_month
    , count(o.OrderDate) this_year
from customers c
LEFT join orders o on c.id = o.c_id
                  and OrderDate >= @this_year
                  and OrderDate < dateadd(year,1,@this_year)
group by c.Id, c.name
having count(case when o.OrderDate >= @last_month and o.OrderDate < @this_month then 1 end) = 0
and count(o.OrderDate) > 0
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts. Here is the exact need of the issue. **I need to exclude the customers from the result(get all orders for current year) if they had any purchase in November, also I need results for this year alone**.

Comment: why not specify the real question in the first place? and why cannot you adapt what I have given you to meet those different requirements - it isn't hard to do. try it.

Comment: `dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, getdate() ), 0)` gives you the first of Jan of the current year

Comment: Actually I mentioned the real question in post, for better clarity I updated the question. Also I did tried  the query u gave it was good. But I need all customers from orders table excluding the customers (not orders) who has purchased in last month. Main thing I wanna know alternate way to achieve this other than SubQuery. Sorry if you have any confusion.

Comment: and you still can't see how simply changing a  couple of things would achieve this?

Comment: after you see the second query, tell me you understand what the changes were